Sum of simple functions for a lebesgue integral
I've got troubles with the following fact.
Let $s,t:X\to[0,+\infty)$ such that $s=\sum_{n=1}^ka_n\mathbf{1}_{A_n}$ and $t=\sum_{m=1}^h b_m\mathbf{1}_{B_m}$ two simple functions and suppose that $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^k$ and $\{B_m\}_{m=1}^h$ are pairwise disjoint cover of $X$.
So, I get that $(A_n\cap B_m)\cap (A_j\cap B_l)=\emptyset$ if $(n,m)\ne (j,l)$ an therefore, the family $$\{A_n\cap B_m, \quad n\in \{1,...,k\}, m\in\{1,...,h\}\}$$ is a pairwise disjoint cover of $X$.
Now, taken $n\in \{1,...,k\}, m\in\{1,...,h\}$ I want to understand why $$\int_{A_n\cap B_m} (s+t)\ d\mu=(a_n+b_m)\mu(A_n\cap B_m)$$ and I tried to write an explicit form of $s+t$, so:
$$s+t=\sum_{n=1}^k\sum_{m=1}^h(a_n+b_m)\mathbf{1}_{A_n\cap B_m}$$
But what I can do now? I think that $A_n\cap B_m$ is disjointed from the other intersections can help.

Let us define
$C_{n,m}:=A_n\cap B_m$, then you have already understood that those $C_{n,m}$ form a pairwise disjoint cover of $X$. Further, you have also correctly displayed the function $s+t$, we have
$$s+t=\sum_{n,m=1}^{k,h}(a_n+b_m)\mathbf 1_{C_{n,m}}.$$
This map is constant on each of the sets $C_{n,m}$. More precisely, let $x\in C_{i,j}$ then we have
$$ (s+t)(x) =(a_i+b_j)\underbrace{\mathbf 1_{C_{i,j}}(x)}_{=1}+ \sum_{n,m\neq i,j}(a_n+b_m)\underbrace{\mathbf1_{C_{n,m}} (x)}_{=0} = a_i+b_j.$$
So for the integral we have now
$$\int_{C_{i,j}} (s+t)(x)\;\mathrm d \mu(x) \overset{x\in C_{i,j}}= \int_{C_{i,j}} (a_i+b_j)\;\mathrm d \mu(x)=(a_i+b_j) \int_{C_{i,j}} 1 \;\mathrm d\mu(x)=(a_i+b_j)\, \mu(C_{i,j}).$$
